# Get the timestamp of max value in TDengine

Tags: sql, tdengine

I'm trying to downsample with `interval` in TDengine.

I have a statement:

```
select _wstart, max(val) max_val, min(val) min_val from d1001 interval(5s);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd5w1.png)

You can see in the picture, and it is ok.

Now I want to get the timestamp for max/min value, how should I change the sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it needs to be understood that the timestamps of the maximum and minimum values are different. So they need to be obtained separately.

You can try:

```
select ts, max(val) max_val from d1001 interval(5s);
```

or

```
select ts, max(val) max_val from d1001 interval(5s);
```